# How to use DATE_ADD to compare date in range in Doctrine and Symfony2 using createQueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables related to each other (main_table OneToMay detail_table). There is a `deadline_days` field in main table and a `create_date` in detail_table. I want to select all details which `create_date`+`main.deadline_days` are passed base on today date. (This was the scenario)

This is the proper MySQL query which gives me right records

```
SELECT  `D`.* FROM `details_table` AS  `D` 
INNER JOIN  `main_table` AS  `M` ON (`D`.`Main_Id` = `M`.`id`) 
WHERE DATE_ADD(`D`.`Create_Date`, INTERVAL  `M`.`Deadline_days` DAY) <= NOW()
```

Now in Symfony when I want to create the query using `createQueryBuilder` it comes with this error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 165: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_COMMA, got 'M'
```

This is what I have for now in my query builder

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('D')
->join('D.Main', 'M')
->where('DATE_ADD(D.Create_Date, INTERVAL M.DeadLine_Days DAY) <= NOW()')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

*Please do not suggest using native query*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I found base on this link ([Doctrine Update DQL function signature](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions))
Doctrine2 has function `DATE_ADD` but does not have INTERVAL param as MySQL, also the unit param should be as string `'DAY'`; so the Query should be:

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('D')
   ->join('D.Main', 'M')
   ->where('DATE_ADD(D.Create_Date, M.DeadLine_Days, 'DAY') <= CURRENT_DATE()')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

*In doctrine we should use `CURRENT_DATE()` instead of `NOW()`*

Comment: The ref. link to function signatures is very useful. The important part is that the *units* needs an *' (apos)* and not a *" (double quotes)* or it will throw exception